# How can I read from an XML-string in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, xml, opencv

I know how to load/save a `cv::Mat` instance into a XML-file (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621768/how-can-i-save-and-read-from-xml-the-new-c-style-matrix-objects-in-opencv)).

But what I really need, is to parse a `std::string` (or `char *`) that contains the XML, and get the `cv::Mat`. Say I get the XML out of a database, and not from a file.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do it since OpenCV 2.4.1.

Here is a code sample from [release notes](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog#241):

```
//==== storing data ====
FileStorage fs(".xml", FileStorage::WRITE + FileStorage::MEMORY);
fs << "date" << date_string << "mymatrix" << mymatrix;
string buf = fs.releaseAndGetString();

//==== reading it back ====
FileStorage fs(buf, FileStorage::READ + FileStorage::MEMORY);
fs["date"] >> date_string;
fs["mymatrix"] >> mymatrix;
```

Comment: Wonderful. Anyone who met the same problems, You should not write things like FileStorage::READ||FileStorage::MEMORY like other libs - you should use + instead.

Comment: While reading it back, how do you specify the format (YAML/XML)? I ask because I'm writing it as .xml.

Comment: @rdasxy, the format is detected automatically. I don't know for sure but most likely it decides based on XML/YML declaration tag

Comment: @xxbidiao you shouldn't use `+`, what you need is logical OR `|` instead of boolean OR `||`